# Session in "Sql*net message from client", but is active

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I've Googled around, and my impression is that

> Sql*net message from client

suggests the Oracle DBMS is waiting for the client to send new commands to the DBMS, and therefore any time spent in this event should be client-side time and not consume DB server CPUs. In other words, normally, if a session is in this event, it should be "INACTIVE" rather than "ACTIVE".

What's puzzling to us is that starting from this week (after we started using connection pools [we use dbcp]), we occassionally see sessions in the

> Sql*net message from client

event and showing "ACTIVE" at the same time for extended periods of times. And during all this time, CPU usage on the DB is high.

Can anyone shed some light on what this means?  If the DB session is waiting for the client to send a message, what can it be "ACTIVE" and consuming CPU cycles for?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this. Can you please explain?

Comment: this might well be better on dba.stackexchange instead of stackoverflow, it is a vote to migrate it there.

Comment: voted to migrate to [dba.se] @Ray

Comment: I see. Thanks. When it's moved, will I be notified of the new link?

Comment: If you click on the old link it will automatically take you through to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you see this event in the V$SESSION view you need to check the value of the STATE column as well to determine if the session is idle or is in fact working.

This is based on the following Oracle Magazine [article:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42dba-1566567.html)

> you cannot look at the EVENT column alone to find out what the session
>   is waiting for. You must look at the STATE column first to determine
>   whether the session is waiting or working and then inspect the EVENT
>   column.